# Tabulator: HTML code in topCalc calculations

Tags: tabulator

I'm using topCalc with a custom function.

Function is an extension

```
Tabulator.extendModule("columnCalcs", "calculations", {});
```

and it returns a string.

I'd like to return an HTML string, such as

```
return "<span class="ru-enabled">123</span> | <span class="ru-disabled">12</span> | <span class="ru-deleted32</span>";
```

The problem is that on topCalc header cell, the HTML is escaped.

[The function returns a simple text, and that's ok](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ePmIH.png)

[The function returns html code, as said above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxNG7.png)

[The function returns html code (this is what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q51sO.png)

Is there any options I have to set to tell tabulator not to escape HTML and write text/html as is?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a solution, don't know if it's the best.

In the column, I have:

```
topCalc: "usersByStatus"
```

that counts how many users are in Enabled, Disabled, Deleted status (that's why 123 | 12 | 32), and returns something like this

```
_enabled_o_123_enabled_c | _disable_o_12_disabled_c | _deleted_o_32_deleted_c
```

I've added a new option in the column

```
topCalcFormatter: "usersByStatus"
```

This "userByStatus" is an extended module for "formatters" (I know, it's the same name)

The function simply searches and replaces "_xxx_o" and "_xxx_c" with "<span class".